# Getting repeats in beautifulsoup nested tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse through html using beautifulsoup (being called with lxml).
On nested tags I'm getting repeated text

I've tried going through and only counting tags that have no children, but then I'm losing out on data

given:

```
<div class="links">
   <ul class="links inline">
      <li class="comment_forbidden first last">
         <span> to post comments</span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and running:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_info, features = "lxml")
soup.prettify().encode("utf-8")
    for tag in soup.find_all(True):
        if check_text(tag.text): #false on empty string/ all numbers 
            print (tag.text)
```

I get "to post comments" 4 times.
Is there a beautifulsoup way of just getting the result once?

Answer (score 0):

Given an input like

```
<div class="links">
   <ul class="links inline">
      <li class="comment_forbidden first last">
         <span> to post comments1</span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="links">
   <ul class="links inline">
      <li class="comment_forbidden first last">
         <span> to post comments2</span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="links">
   <ul class="links inline">
      <li class="comment_forbidden first last">
         <span> to post comments3</span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

You could do something like

```
[x.span.string for x in soup.find_all("li", class_="comment_forbidden first last")]
```

which would give

```
[' to post comments1', ' to post comments2', ' to post comments3']
```

`find_all()` is used to find all the `<li>` tags of class `comment_forbidden first last` and the `<span>` child tag of each of these `<li>` tag's content is obtained using their `string` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this, try swapping out the parser. I switched to `html5lib` and I no longer have repetitions. It is a costlier parser though, so may cause performance issues.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Answer (score -1):

You can use `find()` instead of `find_all()` to get your desired result only once